# Java-FX failed to load resource exception

Tags: java, javafx, tomcat7, java-web-start, jnlp

I am running my Java-FX application via webstart by tomcat server. 
After signing and versioning of jars I having this problem when am accessing it through web browser.
I am using jnlp and version protocol to start the application through tomcat server.

```
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: 
  (httP://127.0.0.1:8080/gyms/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar?version-id=1.0.1, 1.0.1)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This seems to have ***nothing*** to do with Swing!

Comment: Uh, it's missing commons-collections apparently?

Comment: not everything is there in webapps folder of tomcat.

Comment: These jars are ther still this error is coming

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to work with.

Comment: What more information ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a jnlp-file with a line like this:

```
    <jar href="commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" version="1.0.1" />
```

So you are using the version-based download protocol. This will result in the server looking for a file called `commons-collections-3.2.1__V1.0.1.jar` which apparently is not there.

Bottom line: do not specify two conflicting version-numbers in your jnlp. Decide wether you want to use versioned download and omit the version-number in the `href`-attribute or use simple download and omit the `version`-attribute.

Comment: i m using version based protocol, The version i defined is there after signing of jar , wen i trying access this via webstart it is showing Application error.

Comment: so you got a file called `commons-collections-3.2.1__V1.0.1.jar`?

Comment: yes in the lib folder and that path is in jnlp file also with version.

Comment: have you tried it without versioning to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved because I am using Java 1.7.51 update and also i am usin third api which is not supported in java 8 which is also installed in my desktop.
The program(x86) should not have any version of java greater than java 7 as the application is taking java/bin from x86 only. 
that is why that failed download exception is coming at run time.